# Convert columns in (.csv) file to (.json) column array in Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, columnsorting

I am trying to convert a (.csv) file to a .json file which is stored in the form of a column array.

The **input (.csv) file** is:

[image]

This is my **desired result**:

```
{
   "wavelength":[0.033962528,0.035974933,0.03801894,0.039994474,0.041975898,0.043954162],
   "n":[0.842171,0.83072,0.819753,0.809997,0.802291,0.797737],
   "k":[0.090738197,0.10934279,0.13025372,0.15338756,0.17980019,0.20882868],
   "alpha":[33573761.42,38194428.97,43052660.58,48194781.27,53826980.05,59703529.05],
   "absorption_length":[2.98e-8,2.62e-8,2.32e-8,2.07e-8,1.86e-8,1.67e-8]
}
```

I am using this **script**:

```
import csv
import json

with open('test.csv') as infile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(infile)
    out = [{"wavelength": row['wavelength'],"n": row["n"], "k": row["k"],, "alpha": ["alpha"]} for row in reader]

with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(out, outfile)
```

But I am getting the following:

```
[{"wavelength": "0.033962528", "n": "0.842171", "k": "0.090738197", "alpha": ["alpha"]}, 
{"wavelength": "0.035974933", "n": "0.83072", "k": "0.10934279", "alpha": ["alpha"]}, 
{"wavelength": "0.03801894", "n": "0.819753", "k": "0.13025372", "alpha": ["alpha"]},
 {"wavelength": "0.039994474", "n": "0.809997", "k": "0.15338756", "alpha": ["alpha"]}, 
{"wavelength": "0.041975898", "n": "0.802291", "k": "0.17980019", "alpha": ["alpha"]}, 
{"wavelength": "0.043954162", "n": "0.797737", "k": "0.20882868", "alpha": ["alpha"]}]
```

I am trying to get the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way

```
import csv
import json

with open('test.csv') as infile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(infile)
    out = [{"wavelength": row['wavelength'],"n": row["n"], "k": row["k"], "alpha": ["alpha"]} for row in reader]
keys = out[0].keys()
ref_out = {key: [i[key] for i in out ] for key in keys} 


    
with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(ref_out, outfile)
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged `pandas`, this is very easy:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, ...)
result_dict = df.to_dict(orient='list')
```

You can now `json.dump` this dict to a file, assuming that's the end goal.